# Does anyone have a copy of Oracle Java SE Critical Patch Update for Java 7.0.40.22 32-bit

Tags: java, patch, software-update

I ran Belarc Advisor which advises me I am missing the Oracle Java SE Critical Patch Update for Java 7.0.40.22 32-bit (CpuOct2013-1899837).

You need an Oracle support contract to obtain this patch.

Can anyone supply one freely?

Comment: Wants someone to share a binary. Seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the latest "Oracle Critical Patch Update Advisory - January 2014" with the latest Java: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpujan2014-1972949.html

It should have that (and others) bugs patched.

Comment: Clicking on any of the links take you to a page where you need a support contract to log in.

Comment: You need free account and not a Support Contract. Release notes for Java: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html Juts download latest version!

Comment: Java control panel applet says I have the latest Java version, yet Belarc Advisor advises me I am missing the patch.  Weird.

Comment: I didn't have the latest version of Java.  The control panel applet was mistaken.  I downloaded & installed latest version of Java, ran Belarc Advisor again, and the patch was no longer missing.